# nosql dynamodb sort and partition key

Tags: python, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a dynamodb server, which is nosql.

My table is like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    product_id     section product_name  partition_key             sort_key |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0         100  electronic        mouse              0  2022-05-28 15:02:13 |
| 1         200  electronic    key board              1  2022-05-28 15:02:13 |
| 2         300        cats   cat feeder              2  2022-05-28 15:02:13 |
| 3         400        cats  cat drinker              3  2022-05-28 15:02:13 |
| 4         500        food        pizza              4  2022-05-28 15:02:13 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is what I did in pandas:

```
df['partition_key'] = df.index + len(len_tbl)

sql_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
add_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')).strftime(sql_format)
df['sort_key'] = add_date  # creationDate
```

My doubt is related to the most efficient way to build either partition_key and sort_key due the shape of this table, and I'm gonna insert like 500k~1m+ lines per month, so its gonna be huge after some time.

Never worked with nosql, just sql.

Can you share some hints with me?

Comment: Your table design is based mainly / solely on the queries you will want to perform on the table. You need to figure out the queries and then design the schema accordingly.

Comment: So I left out the schema something very important:
It will have one column with the quantity of the product, for example:

product_name: mouse; quantity: 50; date X
product_name: mouse; quantity: 20; date Y
Quantity = 50-20 = 30 sold.

This is the type of queries that I'll do.

Comment: To get the most from DynamoDB you need to design you table and items around how you need to access you data. This may mean storing you data in unintuitive ways. Your question does not include how you plan to use (access) the data, so it is not possible to give advice unless the question is updated